# How to set Panel to homepage when setting the panel's path as homepage on Configuration > Site Information doesn't work?

Tags: panels

I have created a panel for my home page and set its path to /home. I have changed the directory of the front page in Admin > Configuration > Site Information to mysite.com/home. Still, when I visit mysite.com/home, the custom panel saved to path /home doesn't populate.

I've made sure I'm saving correctly (rather than just updating) and have also cleared my cache.

Any ideas how else I might be able to fix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you have done it right.
I assume you don't have domain module install.
Also can you let me know what page is loading instead of your panel page?

Comment: A blank page with only (1) the site logo and slogan and (2) small copyright/social media links at the bottom. It's as if it's overriding the page that should be displayed (the page with all of the panel content) with a blank front page. Any thoughts? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, as an update, when I am in the front-page panel (the one I'm wanting to be my front page), when I click the "Make Home Page" check box in the Basic section of the Panels Module, then save and refresh mysite.com/front-page, the front page shows the blank content I've described before AND the Panels module gets rid of the "Make Home Page" check box in the Basic section. This prevents me from unselecting as my front page and causes me to have to recreate the front-page Panel to be able to see the content on mysite.com/front-page.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what programes interferring the home page redirect.
However, you can try variable_set('site_frontpage', 'front-page-panel-url');

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set

Answer (score 0):

fix the issue instead of hacking your backend. Usually a module needs an update, or you didn't use the right type of panel. Did you setup a node template in Panels by enabling ...

System  page_manager    node_view   Node template   /node/%node In code  ( Enable )

You have to go into Pages under the Structure menu. Then after you create the template you can create a page with the box that says "make this panel my front page".